# Как добавить анимацию к свг ?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

Задавал здесь же вопрос про эту цифру, а как добавить всю это анимацию в css, к примеру если класс дать, тогда будет анимация. Хочу сделать, так чтоб при клике к примеру на кнопку цифра плавно закрашивалась.

```css
svg text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70px;
  fill: url(#fendTestGrad);
}

#fendTestGrad .start {
  stop-color: #c2c5cc;
}
#fendTestGrad .end {
  stop-color: #8f98a1;
}

svg {
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(73,85,97,1) 0%, rgba(74,88,101,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fendTestGrad" x1="52%" y1="52%" x2="48%" y2="48%">
        <animate 
          attributeName="x1" 
          from="0" to=".52"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="y1" 
          from="0" to=".52"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="x2" 
          from="0" to=".48"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="y2" 
          from="0" to=".48"         
          dur="3s" 
          repeatCount="1">          
        </animate>
      
      <stop class="start"></stop>
      <stop class="start"></stop>
      <stop class="end"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text x="50%" y="70">60</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать аттрибут `begin`. Например, этот код запускает анимацию по клику на этом объекте:

```
<animate ... begin = "click" >
```

Проблема в том, что `<linearGradient>` это не объект на который можно кликать. Когда вы кликаете по тексту, это не клик по элементу `<text>`, а не `<linearGradient>`.
Поэтому нужно задать `<text>` какой-нибудь `id`:

```
<text id="textid" x="50%" y="70">60</text>
```

Затем оформить `<animate>` следующим образом:

```
<animate ... begin = "textid.click" >
```

Рабочий код:

```css
svg text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 70px;
  fill: url(#fendTestGrad);
}

#fendTestGrad .start {
  stop-color: #c2c5cc;
}
#fendTestGrad .end {
  stop-color: #8f98a1;
}

svg {
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(73,85,97,1) 0%, rgba(74,88,101,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="fendTestGrad" x1="52%" y1="52%" x2="48%" y2="48%">
        <animate 
          attributeName="x1" 
          from="0" to=".52"         
          dur="3s" begin="textid.click"
          >          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="y1" 
          from="0" to=".52"         
          dur="3s" begin="textid.click"
         >          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="x2" 
          from="0" to=".48"         
          dur="3s" begin="textid.click"
         >          
        </animate>
        <animate 
          attributeName="y2" 
          from="0" to=".48"         
          dur="3s" begin="textid.click"
          >          
        </animate>
      
      <stop class="start"></stop>
      <stop class="start"></stop>
      <stop class="end"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <text id="textid" x="50%" y="70">60</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй так

```
svg{transition: .3s;}
button:focus svg{твой бекграунд; }
```

Comment: Да это я уже в jquery сделаю, мне нужно чтоб само обтекание было по клику или любому другому действию.